# UITableViewCell not showing UILabel within

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uitableview, uilabel

I have this code and it gives the result of the screenshot below. It's in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. I don't know why the text above the bars isn't showing. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: cell.textLabel.frame];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%% (%i)",([[options_votes objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] intValue] * 100.0 / total_votes),[[options_votes objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] intValue]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%% (%i)",([[options_votes objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] intValue] * 100.0 / total_votes),[[options_votes objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] intValue]]);
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    [label release];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: cell.textLabel.frame];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.text = [options objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[options objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    [label release];
    UIImageView * image_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nav_delegate->back_bar];
    image_view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 44, 280, 10);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image_view];
    [image_view release];
    image_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nav_delegate->blue_bar];
    image_view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 44, 5 + [[options_votes objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] intValue] * 275.0/total_votes, 10);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image_view];
    [image_view release];
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a stab in the dark, but because you did `cell.textLabel.text = @"";`, it might have shrank the frame of the textLabel there to a width of 0. Try creating your labels based off of a frame that you know to be of a correct visible size.

Comment: Okay thank you. It does work somewhere else using that frame. I will try changing it though

Answer (score 1):

To show your 2 labels, you can use this code:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 10, 280, 25)];
        label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label1.text = @"Your Text Here";
        label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
        [label1 release];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 10, 280, 25)];
        label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label2.text = @"Your Text Here";
        label2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label2];
        [label2 release];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        // Put your imageView code here.
    }
```

Note: if you are using a tableViewCell taller than defaults size, 44.0, you can change the 25 number in the initWithFrame method of the labels.
Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Thank you but as you can see on the image, I want multiple labels per row. Also, in your code I'd use an if...else structure or switch statement.